# SQL : Display Chunk data from huge list performance

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have to fetch n number of records from the database. The count of this record may very manager to manager. It means one manager can have 100+ records and other may have only 50+ records.

If it is all about fetching data from only one table then its super easy to get.

In my case the main pain point is I will get my result after using so many **joins** , **temp** tabels , functions , **maths** on some column and dates filter using switch cases and many more and yes each tables has 100k+ records with proper indexing.

I have added **pagination** in UI side so that I can get only 20 records at a time on screen. once I clicked on page number based on that I should offset the records for next 20. Supposed clicked on page number 3 then from db I should get only records from 41- 60.

UI part is not a big deal the point is how to optimise your query so that every time I should get only 20 records.

My current implementation is every time I am calling the same procedure with index value to offset the data. Is that correct way to run same complex with all functions , cte, cases in filters and inner/left joins again and again to fetch only piece of data from recordset.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: Your manager needs to press Next on your page _2,000_ times to get to the end of a 30k recordset. That is not a sensible user requirement. What is the real requirement here? Do they want to export data? get a summary?

Comment: Point is how to achieve this without impacting performance... Forget about the requirements dear...

Comment: Bdw I have updated my Post..

Comment: 100k records is small table, so what is your actual problem? No proper indexing? Usage of multi statement / scalar functions or views in a wrong place? Example of the case where performance is poor?

Comment: Yes 100k records small  if you are fetching data from one table.. but it becomes performance issue when you have to fetch it from multiple tables using joins, function , cte etc... And for every next 20 records I have to perform same query and then using offset to get the next 20 records  based on the page number you have clicked.... Don't you thing it will be a performance issue

Comment: Matching a silly solution to a silly requirement: cache the lot on the client side. Matching a vague solution to a vague requirement: if your SQL statement is slow, optimise with indexes and logic rewrites

Comment: So if I understand correctly, every request sent, whether it's the first page or the fifth page, is slow. You haven't explained whether you're doing paging in the SQL Statement or on the web page. If you have a DB performance issue you need to provide enough info to help.

Comment: If you're doing paging in the SQL query / controller, then that impacts SQL performance. If you're doing paging purely in the UI it means you are getting the entire recordset in which case you should just cache it

Comment: I have updated my questions as per your query... Let me know if you want me add anything

Comment: So if you never expect more than 200 records, it would make sense to do client side paging. That is, load all records to the client and use some javascript fanciness to implement paging. You probably want to hard limit the database records returned to 500 though.

Comment: This question is fundamentally about SQL Performance and there is insufficient info to solve that

Comment: It's taking too much time to fetch like 60 seconds +

Comment: And it may very with nth records.. it can't restrict to 100 or 200 only..

Comment: We already know there is a performance issue. To solve a performance issue, we would need to know all the tables involved, rowcounts, what indexes they have, what the actual query plan is... that kind of stuff. Are you in a position to understand and add that info? If you don't know what the upper limit of returned records is, and you want to continue implementing pagination of possibly thousands of records, then client side pagination is not really a solution, you need to solve your SQL performance issue.

Comment: I do understand dear and I have checked everything regarding the indexes and all and everything is ok.. the problem is I won't share my code here bcz of company policy... :(

Comment: If everything is "OK" in your code then the only option to improve SQL Performance is to get a bigger server.